# Using if to have different elements on different pages in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a certain div class (landing), that I only want to have appear on certain routes.  I am using a "main" template that has my header and footer (with a >yield included between for each pages unique code).  However, there is an element in the header that I only want to appear on the landing page ('/' route).

I am using Iron Router.

Is there a way to do this easily with an #if in meteor?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generic route name equality testing helper:

```
Template.registerHelper('routeEquals',function(name){
  return Router.current().route.getName() === name;
});
```

Then in any template you can do (for example):

```
{{#if routeEquals '/'}}
  in the / route
{{else}}
  Not in the / route
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a session flag in the `onBeforeAction` of the landing route and then, on the header, check if that session is valid and show the `div`

Something like this

```
this.route("landing", {
    path: "/landing", 
    onBeforeAction: function () {
        Session.set('showDiv', true);  
    }
});

<template name='main'>
   <header>{{#if helper_getShowDivFlag}}<div></div>{{/if}}</header>
</template>

helper_getShowDivFlag: function() {
   return Session.get('showDiv');
}
```

Alternatively, checking the router name in the main template and show/hide the `div`

```
<template name='main'>
   <header>{{#if helper_showDivFlag}}<div></div>{{/if}}</header>
</template>

helper_showDivFlag: function() {
    return Router.current().route.getName() == 'landing'
}
```

Or if you don't want to write code, use this [package](https://github.com/zimme/meteor-active-route) and check  the router :D

```
<template name='main'>
       <header>{{#if isActiveRoute 'landing' }}<div></div>{{/if}}</header>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a helper on your header template that reactively checks the current route. I haven't used Iron Router in a while, but *believe* `Router.current().route.getName()` is reactive. Try the following:

```
Template.header.helpers({
  onLanding() {
    return Router.current().route.getName() === '<landingRouteName>';
  },
});

<template name="header">
  {{#if onLanding}}
  <div>I should only show on the landing page!</div>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Or, alternatively (and maybe optimally - it would keep the template loaded, rather than injecting it into the DOM when you hit landing), you can use the helper to apply a class like

```
<div class="{{#if onLanding}}isVisible{{/if}}>...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using the `data` property of your route.

```
Router.route('/', {
    name: 'home',
    data: function() {
        return {
            showMySpecialHeaderWidget: true
        };
    }
});
```

Then you can access this data property in your template.

```
<template name="main">
    <header>
        {{#if showMySpecialHeaderWidget}}
            <div>My special header widget</div>
        {{/if}}
    </header>

    {{> yield}}
</template>
```

Using this method, you don't need to worry about updating your template if you ever change the names of your routes, and it's easy to show your widget on multiple routes by including this data property.